# Enable rest communication for pods running java images

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, microservices

So, this is the setup:

- each pod will run one container (java application)
- each pod provides its own UI
- for each java app there is a mysql DB which it needs to access
- for each java app its necessary to retrieve and provide information using rest calls

It is some kind of the classic containerized microservice architecture.

**The requirement is to enable the applications to request and provide information for other application running on different pods.** But as I need to set these calls up before I push them to the cluster I have, to be honest, no idea how it should work.

E.g. I got an application which is using another rest interface to request data:

```
public List<Article> getArticles() {
        String url = http://ip:port/article/getAllArticles/;
        HttpEntity entity = prepareHttpEntity();
        ResponseEntity<List> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, List.class);
        return response.getBody();
    }
```

**How I can make sure to it is connecting to the right service (pod)?**

Same for the DB setup. I need to tell the application the `datasource`, which is unknown yet.

**Is there some kind of best practice to deal with these issues?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each **Pod** when created will have its own cluster-private IP, but you never depend on it, as pods are *ephemeral*. If you want to talk to a **Pod**, you create a [***Service***](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) that routes traffic to the pod.

```
restCall --> Service --> Pod
```

Let's say you have the following Pod definition

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: appAPod
  labels:
    app: appA
spec:
  containers:
  - name: aNameForApp1Container
    image: yourRepository/imageName:tag
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
  ...
```

Then, you make it accessible by creating a Service Definition:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: serviceA
spec:
  selector:
    app: appA
  ports:
  - name: serviceAPort
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
```

So the way you connect a **Pod** and a **Service** is via *labels* and *selector*. Now, you can hit your pod with the following url :

```
http://serviceA:80
```

In your second app, you will have the following Pod Definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: appBPod
  labels:
    app: appB
spec:
  containers:
  - name: aNameForApp2Container
    image: yourRepository/imageName2:tag
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
    env:
    - name: "APP_A_ADDRESS"
      value: serviceA
    - name: "APP_A_PORT"
      value: 80
```

Since you're using RestTemplate, I assume you are using Spring. So in your application.properties :

```
..
..
appA.baseUrl=http://${APP_A_ADDRESS}:${APP_A_PORT}
```

And in your code:

```
@Value("${appA.baseUrl}")
String appABaseUrl;

public List<Article> getArticles() {
        String url = appABaseUrl + "/article/getAllArticles/";
        HttpEntity entity = prepareHttpEntity();
        ResponseEntity<List> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, List.class);
        return response.getBody();
}
```

---

You should consider [Deplyments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/), instead of a Pod, as it offers you more flexibility and control over your containers.

If you are going to containerize your DB, then you might want to check out [Persistent Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)